# I am not sure if mining has started with ethminer

Tags: mining, ethminer, geth-debugging

```
0:28
m  15:38:55|ethminer  Got work package: #6c0f3492
m  15:38:56|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0]     Time: 00:28
m  15:38:56|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
m  15:38:57|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
m  15:38:58|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
m  15:38:58|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
m  15:38:59|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
m  15:39:00|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:28
```

I see this in my console, it says Got work package but I see all 0s. Have I started mining or is something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the fact is that you are not mining because your HashRate is too low and then the pool protocols decided to put you out.

First, check your Hash Power using:

`ethminer -G -M`

With the result, divide it by 1E6 and this is your hashrate on MHs/s. If the result is greater than 1 at least, you can mine on a normal pool.

If the first test was Ok, then reinstall your GPU drivers and set the correct hashrate before start mining.

Just in case, if you are not mining with GPU, you have to specify it, because not doing it can cause issues like you have.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Either your speed is < 1 kilohash (very slow), or you are not mining. 
Are you using a pool? If so try reconfiguring the settings so you are receiving work.

Comment: I got this now but it's not moving. Does it mean i'm mining?    miner  21:06:11.965|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #01fc8957… : 0 H/s = 0 hashes / 0.507 s
miner  21:06:12.364|ethminer  Got work package:
miner  21:06:12.364|ethminer    Header-hash: c55fcecb8f9c246c483111d27824df1c84333de1f8c127fe1ff78dfcac19c961
miner  21:06:12.364|ethminer    Seedhash: 19b5edd80fa59xxxxxxxd7d972b71b06de8ac10e35
miner  21:06:12.364|ethminer    Target: 00000000dbe6fecxxxxxxxxx912adcb8d8422e

Comment: You still aren't hashing anything, so I would assume no. Either your computer is messed up(less likely), your internal config isnt setup property, or your pool isn't feeding you anything.

Comment: any pointers on how to setup internal config? I think I am using the right pool and I think my computer is ok.

Comment: What pool are you using?

Comment: Tried a few http://eth-eu1.nanopool.org:8888/ being the main one

Comment: And what mining software are you using?

Comment: I'm using MinerGate